# I am trying to load the tidyverse library, but I am getting an error message

Tags: r, tidyverse

First time using R, very new to coding. I'm trying to open the tidyverse library (I think that's the correct terminology) and I keep getting this error code:

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/(myusername)/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.0.2
```

I have updated my Rstudio by pressing the "Update" button under the Packages tab, but I don't think that's working, or what is causing the issue. Is the problem that I have a "shared object" in the wrong folder, or do I need an updated version of tidyverse? Or potentially something else? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you installed the package?

Comment: @Peter yes I have installed tidyverse, I used this line of code to do so: install.packages("tidyverse")

Comment: If Rcpp.dll is missing, `install.packages("Rcpp")` should solve the problem.

Comment: I installed Rcpp.dll using the code provided, and then I tried to open the library again, but I got the same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem lies in the system version of R and Rstudio. I have in my computer home 64 bit system. I have installed the new version of R 4.0.2 and Rstudio 1.3... (64 bit). I run install.packages("tidyverse") everythings looks good. However, in my computer at office I have system version 32 bit. I does not work even I installed the new version of R 4.0.2. but I still have Rstudio older version.